# Apache ActiveMQ Starts then Stops Abruptly On Windows

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am running apachemq on windows xp.I have no web server services running or any database of any sort,but i keep on getting this error once i start active mq

> ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost,
>   ID:computer_1-3725-13902958 73141-0:1], java.net.URISyntaxException:
>   Illegal character in hostname at index 13:
>   ws://computer_1:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857
>   600)

This is the complete log

```
C:\apache_activemq>.\bin\activemq
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.7.0_21 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre
  Heap sizes: current=1013632k  free=996854k  max=1013632k
    JVM args: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.c
onfig.file=logging.properties -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=admins -Dhaw
tio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal -Djava.security
.auth.login.config=C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\conf\login.config -Dactivemq.classp
ath=C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\conf;C:\apache_activemq\bin\../conf;C:\apache_acti
vemq\bin\../conf; -Dactivemq.home=C:\apache_activemq\bin\.. -Dactivemq.base=C:\a
pache_activemq\bin\.. -Dactivemq.conf=C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\conf -Dactivemq.
data=C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\data -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\d
ata\tmp
Extensions classpath:
  [C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\lib,C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\lib\camel,C:\apache_a
ctivemq\bin\..\lib\optional,C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\lib\web,C:\apache_activemq
\bin\..\lib\extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: C:\apache_activemq\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: C:\apache_activemq\bin\..
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@726b5b: startu
p date [Tue Jan 21 12:17:33 EAT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | PListStore:[C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] starte
d
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\apache_activemq\b
in\..\data\kahadb]
 INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099
/jmxrmi
 INFO | KahaDB is version 5
 INFO | Recovering from the journal ...
 INFO | Recovery replayed 14 operations from the journal in 0.16 seconds.
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 (localhost, ID:computer_1-3725-1390295873141-0:1)
is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=100
0&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector openwire started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=100
0&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector amqp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1
000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector stomp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=100
0&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector mqtt started
ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, ID:computer_1-3725-13902958
73141-0:1], java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index
13: ws://computer_1:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857
600)
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 (localhost, ID:computer_1-3725-1390295873141-0:1)
is shutting down
 INFO | Connector openwire stopped
 INFO | Connector amqp stopped
 INFO | Connector stomp stopped
 INFO | Connector mqtt stopped
 INFO | Connector ws stopped
 INFO | PListStore:[C:\apache_activemq\bin\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] stoppe
d
 INFO | Stopping async queue tasks
 INFO | Stopping async topic tasks
 INFO | Stopped KahaDB
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 (localhost, ID:computer_1-3725-1390295873141-0:1)
uptime 13.059 seconds
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 (localhost, ID:computer_1-3725-1390295873141-0:1)
is shutdown
 INFO | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@726b5b: startup d
ate [Tue Jan 21 12:17:33 EAT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
 WARN | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refr
esh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.apache.activemq.xbea
n.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@726b5b: startup date [Tue Jan 21 12:17:33 EAT 2014]; root
 of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLif
ecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClos
e(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(
AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
        at org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook.run(SpringContextHook.jav
a:30)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:782)

        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.
java:122)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:574
)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBean
BrokerService.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(
ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(
ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFact
ory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext
(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBroker
Factory.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.j
ava:71)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.j
ava:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand
.java:87)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractC
ommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand
.java:150)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractC
ommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.ja
va:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.la
ng.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call '
refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: java.lang.Ille
galStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh
' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand
.java:91)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractC
ommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand
.java:150)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractC
ommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.ja
va:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or alrea
dy closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationCon
text.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destro
yBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:487)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(
ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(
ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFact
ory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext
(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBroker
Factory.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.j
ava:71)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.j
ava:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand
.java:87)
        ... 10 more
ERROR: java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already c
losed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed -
 call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationCon
text.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destro
yBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:487)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(
ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(
ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFact
ory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext
(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBroker
Factory.java:67)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.j
ava:71)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.j
ava:54)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand
.java:87)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractC
ommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand
.java:150)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractC
ommand.java:57)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.ja
va:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
C:\apache_activemq>
```

My `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` looks like this

127.0.0.1   localhost

127.0.0.1   mpa.one.microsoft.com

My activemq.xml looks like this

```
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- START SNIPPET: example -->
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Allows log searching in hawtio console -->
    <bean id="logQuery" class="org.fusesource.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>


        <!--
            The managementContext is used to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in
            JMX. By default, ActiveMQ uses the MBean server that is started by
            the JVM. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html
        -->
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="true"/>
        </managementContext>

        <!--
            Configure message persistence for the broker. The default persistence
            mechanism is the KahaDB store (identified by the kahaDB tag).
            For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html
        -->
        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>


          <!--
            The systemUsage controls the maximum amount of space the broker will
            use before disabling caching and/or slowing down producers. For more information, see:
            http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html
          -->
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <!--
            The transport connectors expose ActiveMQ over a given protocol to
            clients and other brokers. For more information, see:

            http://activemq.apache.org/configuring-transports.html
        -->
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

How should i fix this error?.

Comment: please check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990718/where-can-i-manually-configure-activemq-hostname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My hostname which is localhost did not contain any underscores.The only underscore was in my computer name.My old name was `computer_1` but i changed it to `computer1` and now i am able to use `localhost:8161` activemq web console.

To know how to change the computer name when on windows,do google it or refer to windows documentation.This error has nothing to do with hostname proper but rather the computer name.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem. The problem gone after reboot. Try to reboot PC and start activemq first.
Probably it related that some ports were already taken.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "activemq.log" in your "data" folder, in my case I obtain this error because I was using a "redeliveryPlugin" and it requires a schedulerSupport="true" in broker definition.